# How is the best way to load an array of objects from json of differentes types in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, reflection

I want to do **reflection** with typescript. I have this structure:

```
class Base {
  public id: number;
  public typeName: string; // name of this type
}

class Extend1 extends Base {
  public foo: string;
}

public Extend2 extends Base {
  public someProperty: boolean;
}
```

So I have this json got by HttpClient :

```
const json = [
  {id: 1, typeName: "Extend1", name: "toto"},
  {id: 2, typeName: "Extend2", someProperty: true}
];
```

I find a generic method to load this json by reflection, in respect of class type (defined in typeName property).

So the results must to be an array where the first element is of type Extend1 and the second of type Extend2.

Something like :

```
const myArray : Base[] = loadFromJson(json);

myArray[0] instanceof Extend1; // true;
myArray[1] instanceof Extend2; // true;
```

What is the **best** way to do that ?

**OBS**: I don't want to make a switch like :

```
switch(json.typeName) {
  case 'Extend1': return new Extend1();
  break;
}
```

**BUT**

```
return Object.createInstance(json.typeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, TS is funky when it comes to types, objects, interfaces, and JSON deserialisation.

Let's take a quick trip down memory lane (for me).

We had some objects, because, you know, OOP.

```
export class MyObject {
    public someProperty: string;

    public AddSomething(str: string): void {
        this.someProperty += str;
    }
}
```

What a delightful little object.

When we got our response from the API, something like this, all seemed good;

```
[
    {"someProperty": "hello"},
    {"someProperty": "world"}
]
```

But then when we were doing stuff with our objects and wanted to make use of the super helpful method provided...

```
this.data.forEach((x: MyObject) => {
    x.addSomething('!');
});
```

... it told us that there was no such method `addSomething` on the objects!

Wut?

So, here's the thing: types are an illusion.

TS/JS just parsed the json into a basic object, a dictionary of stuff. Unlike, for example, C# where deserialising something actually creates an instances of that object, E.g.:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject<IEnumerable<MyObject>>(str);
```

Every item in that `result` list will be a concrete `MyObject` object. Under the hood, it does its whole reflection thing and whatnot and physically does a `new MyObject()`

In TS, it's just a dictionary/object, *not* a concrete `MyObject` object, so it's just:

```
{someProperty: 'hello'}
```

and not:

```
{someProperty: 'hello', addSomething: (str: string) => {...}}
```

So, ultimately that's the question you've asked. How do roll your own automatic C#-like JSON parsing hydration mechanism thingy.

We opted to do a fairly odd thing with our objects, which was to give them funky constructors:

```
export class MyObject {
    public someProperty: string;

    constructor(obj?: any) {
        if (!obj) return;
        this.someProperty = obj.someProperty;
    }
}
```

So that we could do:

```
const concreteObjects: MyObject[] = [];
this.data.forEach((x: MyObject /*ButNotARealMyObject*/) => {
    concreteObjects.push(new MyObject(x));
});
```

Now we have converted from lifeless property bags to actual object types that we can use. Hooray!

Another method is to do something slightly smarter and reusable. Something like [this](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/11/create-and-hydrate-a-typescript-class-from-json/) looks fairly promising...

Looks to be a helper that effectively uses 'reflection' - which in JS/TS is just doing `Object.keys(someObj)` - to go over all the properties that object has with some funky syntax/mechanism I didn't know existed because I haven't previously cared to create instances of the given types.

Still slightly manual, because once you get your response, you need to put in your line `const data = HydrationHelper.hydrate(MyObject, jsonData);` or whatever.

Whenever you need to repetitively do something manually, it means you can do it automatically!

Make yourself a wrapper for the `HttpClient` (assuming you are making some kind of API request to get your data) - frankly, you should be wrapping it anyway, all kinds of benefits to doing that.

So instead of your services directly using `HttpClient`, they'll use your new `HttpService` which gives you a place to alter the response (hydrate your response) before returning it to the calling service.

Taken with a pinch of salt, something like this would come from it:

```
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

    public get<T>(url: string, queryParams: object): Observable<T> {
        url = parseParams(url, queryParams);
        this.http.get(url)
            .pipe(map( /*map might not be the right function, I don't have my IDE up to make sure and at this point I want to go to bed*/
                (x) => {
                    return HydrationHelper.hydrate(T, x);   
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Something like that. I don't know, will to live fading.

I'll spam one last thing out, because it's standard to effectively copy relevant content from any links in case the link dies, so here's the hydrate function from there:

```
function hydrate<T>(constr: { new(...args: any[]): T }, data: string, strictMode: boolean = true, ...args: any[]): T {
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    const instance = new constr(...args);

    for (let key in obj) {
        if (!strictMode || instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            instance[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

And my vague references to `HydrationHelper` would be turning that from a js function to something more typescripty. I don't know why I chose a static class instead of an injectable service, which would be sensible, but whatever, it illustrates the point.

```
export class HydrationHelper {
    public static hydrate<T>(constr: { new(...args: any[]): T }, data: string, strictMode: boolean = true, ...args: any[]): T {
        const obj = JSON.parse(data);
        const instance = new constr(...args);

        for (let key in obj) {
            if (!strictMode || instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                instance[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Oh, actually, one last thing - my first sentence mentioned interfaces, which I haven't done.

We don't bother with classes any more for our basic dtos. Interfaces do the job in the world of TS, seeing as how you don't get a physical instance of your object type anyway. Use helpers/services/whatever or, yes, do all this additional work to get the right types for using various functions to manipulate your data.

Without internal functions, this interface is just as good as the class and you won't run into any deserialisation confusion:

```
export interface MyObject {
    someProperty: string;
}
```

---

Edit: Some digging later and it looks like TS does have the equivalent to C# of being able to get the type from the string - so long as the string is the exact type name.

```
const typeName = 'number'; 
type myType = typeof typeName; 
const x: myType = 5;
```

So given that, altering my first spam slightly, you should, I think be able to do something like:

```
type responseType = typeof response.typeName;
HydrationHelper.hydrate(responseType, response);
```

Try that?

Comment: Thank you very much for this long and clear answer. In the perfect word, this can works perfectly. But in my case, no ! The objects can have properties of other objects of other types and/or array of objects of other types. So, by default I dont know what kind of objects I will get from the API.

Comment: You have no idea what form the data will take? You're just playing guess work? What are you expecting to do with the data once you have it?

Comment: Yes, I have. Buy it can be of many differents types, and the only way I have to know what type must be created is the colmun 'typeName' with the name of the class that must be created.