# How to dynamically calculate the duration of the 'Call' class object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Working on an Angular I'm trying to display a list of calls with their respective duration:

```
export class Call {
  ucid: string;
  state: string;
  originator: Originator;
  destination: Destination;
  language: string;
  server: string;
  creationDate: number;
  duration: string;
}
```

I'm able to get an `Call[]` from a Web API:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.callService.getCalls().subscribe(calls => {
      this.calls = calls;
     });
  }
```

Having the `creationDate` as starting point I want to calculate and display the duration of each call in a format `hh:mm:ss`.

Have tried this with no result:

```
export class Call {

  ucid: string;
  state: string;
  originator: Originator;
  destination: Destination;
  language: string;
  server: string;
  creationDate: number;
  calculateDuration = () => {
    setInterval(function () {
      let duration = this.creationDate + 1;
      this.duration = duration;
      return duration;
    }, 1000);
  };
  duration: any = this.calculateDuration();
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085742/how-is-the-best-way-to-load-an-array-of-objects-from-json-of-differentes-types-i/73086005#73086005) is relevant!

The short version is that TS/Angular/whatever isn't deserialising your request into actual concrete Call objects. Just base `object`s with the shape of it (basically just a dictionary).

You'd need to create `Call` objects from your response if you want to be able to use the method you have in there.

```
const calls = [];
response.forEach((x: Call /*not really a Call object*/) => {
    const call = new Call();
    call.x = x.x;
    call.y = x.y;
    calls.push(call);
});

this.calls = calls;
```

Once done, `this.calls` contains actual `Call` objects that have a `calculateDuration` function available for use.